# one-hot encoding, access list elements

Tags: python, arrays, list, one-hot-encoding

I have a .csv file with data of which i want to transform some columns to one-hot. The problem occurs in the second last line, where the one-hot index (e.g. 1st feature) gets placed in all rows instead of just the one i am in currently.
It seems to be some problem with how i access the 2D list... any suggestions?
thank you

```
def one_hot_encode(data_list, column):
    one_hot_list = [[]]
    different_elements = []

    for row in data_list[1:]:                  # count different elements
        if row[column] not in different_elements:
            different_elements.append(row[column])

    for i in range(len(different_elements)):   # set variable names
        one_hot_list[0].append(different_elements[i])

    vector = []                              # create list shape with zeroes
    for i in range(len(different_elements)):
        vector.append(0)
    for i in range(1460):
        one_hot_list.append(vector)

    ind_row = 1                                # encode 1 for each sample
    for row in data_list[1:]:
        index = different_elements.index(row[column])
        one_hot_list[ind_row][index] = 1     # mistake!! sets all rows to 1
        ind_row += 1
```

Comment: There's still an indent error after the first `if` statement.

Comment: Hi, if any answer below has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark next to it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I removed the word "(solved)" from the question title.  (Most future users who have issues are not going to search for their problem using a term of "solved").  The correct way of saying that your problem is solved is by accepting one of the answers - see the link in Lafexlos' comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem stems from the `vector` object you're creating to do the one-hot encoding; you've created one object, and then built a `one_hot_list` that contains 1460 references to the same object.  When you make a change in one of the rows, it will be reflected in all of the rows.

Quick solution would be to create separate copies of the `vector` for each row (See [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)):

```
one_hot_list.append(vector[:])
```

Some of the other things you're doing in your function are a bit slow or roundabout.  I'd suggest a few changes:

```
def one_hot_encode(data_list, column):
    one_hot_list = [[]]

    # count different elements
    different_elements = set(row[column] for row in data_list[1:])

    # convert different_elements to a list with a canonical order,
    # store in the first element of one_hot_list
    one_hot_list[0] = sorted(different_elements)

    vector = [0] * len(different_elements)   # create list shape with zeroes
    one_hot_list.extend([vector[:] for _ in range(1460)])

    # build a mapping of different_element values to indices into
    # one_hot_list[0]
    index_lookup = dict((e,i) for (i,e) in enumerate(one_hot_list[0]))
    # encode 1 for each sample
    for rindex, row in enumerate(data_list[1:], 1):
        cindex = index_lookup[row[column]]
        one_hot_list[rindex][cindex] = 1
```

This builds `different_elements` in linear time by using the `set` data type, and uses list comprehensions to produce the values for `one_hot_list[0]` (the list of element values which are being one-hot encoded), the zero `vector`, and `one_hot_list[1:]` (which is the actual one-hot-encoded matrix value).  Also, there's a `dict` called `index_lookup` that lets you quickly map element values onto their integer index, instead of searching for them over and over again.  Finally, your row index into the `one_hot_list` matrix can be managed for you by `enumerate`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of what you are trying to do but the problem you are seeing is in these lines:

```
for i in range(1460):
    one_hot_list.append(vector)
```

These are creating the `one_hot_list` as 1460 references to the same vector of zeros.  Whereas I think you want it to be a new vector each time.  A direct fix would just be to copy it each time:

```
for i in range(1460):
    one_hot_list.append(vector[:])
```

But a more Pythonic approach would be to create the list with a comprehension. Perhaps something like this:

```
vector_size = len(different_elements):
one_hot_list = [ [0] * vector_size for i in range(1460)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use set() for counting unique items in the list

```
 different_elements = list(set(data[1:]))
```

Comment: `different_elements` just keeps track of the values of a specific column, not the whole row.  You want `different_elements = list(set(row[column] for row in data[1:]))`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you save yourself from the hassle of re-implementing this in plain Python. You can use use `pandas.get_dummies` for this:

First some test data (`test.csv`):

```
A
Foo
Bar
Baz
```

Then in Python:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
# convert column 'A' to one-hot encoding
pd.get_dummies(df['A'])
```

[image: table]

You can retrieve the underlying `numpy` array using:

```
pd.get_dummies(df['A']).values
```

Which results in:

```
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```